# Vue and Vuex: Can't dispatch an action in a state service

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm trying to dispatch an action in a service. Here's the vue code

```js
import { mapActions} from "vuex";

methods: {
  ...mapActions("user", ["updateUseEmailAction"]),

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.$v.$touch();
    this.$v.$error ? "" : this.updateUser();
  },
  updateUser() {
    console.log("test");
    this.updateUseEmailAction({
      form: this.form,
    });
  },
},
```

user.js

```
import userService from "@/services/userService";

export const state = {
  loading:false,
};

export const actions = {
 updateUserNameAction({ commit }, params) {
 return new Promise(() => {
  userService
    .updateUserName(params)
    .then((data) => {
      this._vm.$toast.success(data.message);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this._vm.$toast.error(err.data.message);
    });
 });
},

updateUserEmailAction({ commit }, params) {
console.log("inside user/updateUserEmailAction");
return new Promise(() => {
  userService
    .updateUserEmail(params)
    .then((data) => {
      this._vm.$toast.success(data.message);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this._vm.$toast.error(err.data.message);
    });
  });
 },
};
```

I get "test" in the log but I get this error

```
unknown local action type: updateUseEmailAction, global type: user/updateUseEmailAction
```

Why does it look for a local action or function named `updateUseEmailAction` and not dispatch it from `user` service? How to fix this?

Comment: Use `namespaced: true,` in vue module

Comment: Your `methods` is in a `export default {` right ? How do your vuex module `user` looks like ? The issue is coming from there essentially, it probably cannot find it for some reason. Because the syntax in the script here is fine IMO.

Comment: added user.js to check. I removed extra getters and setters

Comment: Do you have a `export const userModule = { namespaced: true, state, actions }` at the end of this file (if you replace `export const actions` by `const actions`) ? And also, again: Your methods is in a `export default {` right ? Also, please also edit the new js snippet in terms of formatting.

Comment: that's no ````export const userModule ...```` at the end of the file user.js I export actions and them map th these actions in the vue component

Comment: I mean, can you edit and put the whole file? Also confirm my other question?

Comment: I just changed the action name and it worked. there's a function with the same name but in another file which I didn't import don't know why this conflict happened other file name is userService.js thanks a lot for your efforts.